# How to add directories to class path in boot?

Tags: clojure, classpath, boot

I have the following build.boot file:

```
(set-env!
 :resource-paths #{"src" "dev"}
 :dependencies '[[me.raynes/conch "0.8.0"]])
(task-options!
 pom {:project 'myapp
      :version "0.1.0"}
 jar {:manifest {"Foo" "bar"}})
```

And upon starting it with the cider repl and changing the namespace of the cider repl from boot.user to user, I should have access to this function in user.clj

```
(def go reloaded.repl/go)
```

So that I can call (go), I get the go isn't defined. It seems like the directories in my resource-paths aren't really in my class path as one with a leiningen background would expect. So how do I really add directories to the class path with boot?

Comment: You may want to remove the boot tag from your questions since it refers to the startup phase of an OS… unfortunately I don't know myself how to select the correct tag for Boot as in “Boot, the build tool”

Answer (score 0):

Being rookie myself when it comes to Boot I'm just taking a shot here: Boot distinguishes between `:source-paths` and `:resource-paths`; you only have the latter (with `"src"` in it). So maybe try the following:

```
 :source-paths #{"src" "dev"}
```

AFAIK resources are for static stuff you want to your program to consume or produce. Should you have locations for these purposes add a line like the following:

```
:resource-paths #{"public" "resources"}
```

Maybe this helps…